# progress handler in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've implemented a progress handler in plain javascript, I'm wondering how can I achieve the same using angular data binding feature.

HTML

```
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
```

plain javascript:

```
progressBar.style.width = progress + "%";
```

how can this be translated in angular world, suppose I've an angular app already instantiated and I can set the variable in `$scope`

```
$scope.progress = progress;
```

what I'm not clear how to databind this to width property of progress-bar (div)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngStyle`.

```
 <div class="progress-bar" ng-style="{ 'width': progress + '%' }"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is just by setting a with with [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle):

```
<div class="progress-bar" ng-style="{'width': progress + '%'}"></div>
```

You might want to turn this into a [Angular directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#!) though. This way, the progress bar will be reusable:

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <progress-bar progress="myProgress"></progress-bar>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myProgress = '60';
}).directive('progressBar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      progress: '=progress'
    },
    template: '<div class="progress" ng-style="{width: progress + \'%\'}"></div>'
  };
});
```

Plnk: http://plnkr.co/edit/g1ctSdffrwLmA5sw62uR